# application restart by button on vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

How can I restart the application on vueJS by pressing a button

I try

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
      var self = this;
    self.$forceUpdate();
    });
```

$ forceUpdate () is not suitable for this

I need the analog of pressing ctrl + F5

Comment: what do you mean by `restart the application` ? why not just `location.reload();` ?

Comment: thought vueJS can do it himself

Comment: your suggestion to use location.reload (); well suited for me, specify it as a solution to the question

Comment: its okay, no need to add as answer ,It would be duplicate answer here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Window.location*

```
methods:{
    restart(){
        location.reload();
    }
}
```